# Ошибка при инициализации GLEW

Tags: opengl

Недавно начал изучать OpenGL по [этому](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311234/) уроку. И столкнулся с проблемой при инициализации GLEW, а именно:
[image: Ошибка]
Фрагмент кода:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

В линкере подключена библиотека glew32s.lib

Comment: Ошибка не при инициализации, а при сборке. Линкер не знает где искать функции, на которое вы ссылаетесь в коде.

Comment: Но в линкере прописана glew32s.lib

Comment: Разрядность библиотеки и компилируемой программы совпадает?

Comment: Да, сопадает. Обе 32битные